# Switched greeting on Ubuntu System; now doesn't Work

Tags: boot, 20.04, login, lightdm, bootloader

Yesterday, I switched my available greeting, on my Ubuntu System, from *lightdm-webkit2-greeter* to *slick-greeter* and after I rebooted my system, the boot sequence is stuck on the loading bootup screen for Ubuntu. I attempted to go into advance mode and restart any packages that could cause problems, but I did not have any luck with it. I also attempted to go into ttyl but it would always say that my password is incorrect (even though I put it in correctly). I do have Timeshift enabled, but I do not know how to access it. Worse case scenario, I damaged the login screen and might have to install an entire different os. Please let me know as soon as you can, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How did you switch it?

If the text-mode login screen says your password is wrong, then your password is wrong. The end. If you used special characters that are not on a plain US English QWERTY keyboard then maybe you can't enter it without it being configured. In which case, Google for instructions on how to reset the password and pick one that can be entered with only any plain ASCII characters.